# Не получается реализовать многопроцессорное выполнение программы

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, multiprocessing

Объясните пожалуйста как реализовать многопроцессорное выполнение программы в этом коде:

```
class RelatedQuestionParser(Browser):

    """ Похожие вопросы """

    def __init__(self):

        self.url = 'link'
        self.browser = self.get_browser()    # Получаем браузер
        self.launch_browser(self.url)        # Открываем браузер
        self.page = self.convert_to_bs()     # Создаем объект BeautifulSoup
        self.parsing_process()               # Начинаем парсить


    def convert_to_bs(self):

        """ Получаем объект BeautifulSoup """

        html_source = self.browser.page_source
        page = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'lxml')

        return page


    def parsing_process(self):

        """ Процесс парсинга """

        def get_related_questions():

            """ Получить все похожие вопросы """

            related_questions = self.page.find('div', {'class': 'sidebar-related'}) \
                .find_all('div', {'class': 'spacer'})


            return related_questions


        def get_question_information(question):

            """ Забираем всю нужную информацию с вопроса """

            vote_related_q = question.find('a').find('div').text
            text_related_q = question.find_all('a')[-1].text
            link_related_q = question.find_all('a')[-1]['href']

            done_text_related = html_trans.translate_text(text_related_q)


        related_questions = get_related_questions()    # Все похожие вопросы



a = RelatedQuestionParser()
```

Я делал так, но появляется ошибка `AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'RelatedQuestionParser.parsing_process.<locals>.get_question_information'`:

```
        # Код выше такой же как в первом примере
        ...
        related_questions = get_related_questions()    # Все похожие вопросы

        with multiprocessing.Pool(5) as pool:

            pool.map(get_question_information, related_questions) # Возвращает ошибку
```

Comment: Не думаю, что имеет смысл одну страницу парсить в несколько процессов. Это нужно всё будет сериализовать-десериализовать, чтобы передать в другой процесс. На чём ошибка и выходит. Даже если это починить (не подскажу как, не знаю), не факт, что будет ускорение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам просто следует вынести логику `multiprocessing` на верхний уровень. Внутри себя пул при распаковке повторно ипортирует переданную функцию, для передачи рабочим процессам. Для этого функция должна быть на верхнем уровне, а не внутри класса.

```
class RelatedQuestionParser(Browser):

    """ Похожие вопросы """

    def __init__(self):

        self.url = 'link'
        self.browser = self.get_browser()    # Получаем браузер
        self.launch_browser(self.url)        # Открываем браузер
        self.page = self.convert_to_bs()     # Создаем объект BeautifulSoup
        self.parsing_process()               # Начинаем парсить


    def convert_to_bs(self):

        """ Получаем объект BeautifulSoup """

        html_source = self.browser.page_source
        page = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'lxml')

        return page

    def get_related_questions(self):

        """ Получить все похожие вопросы """

        related_questions = self.page.find('div', {'class': 'sidebar-related'}) 
            .find_all('div', {'class': 'spacer'})


        return related_questions


def get_question_information(question):
    """ Забираем всю нужную информацию с вопроса """

    vote_related_q = question.find('a').find('div').text
    text_related_q = question.find_all('a')[-1].text
    link_related_q = question.find_all('a')[-1]['href']

    done_text_related = html_trans.translate_text(text_related_q)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = RelatedQuestionParser()
    related_questions = a.get_related_questions()

    with multiprocessing.Pool(5) as pool:
        pool.map(get_question_information, related_questions)
```